# How to validate WHERE expression in SQL Server stored procedure (identify SQL injection)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We developed 40+ stored procedures with dynamic SQL by using JSON input expression, something like below

```
{
  "SelectOptions": {
    "Columns": [
      "[ID]",
      "[Title]",
      "[Description]",
      "[Status]",
      "[CreatedByName]"
    ]
  },
  "SortOptions": [
    {
      "SortBy": "[ID]",
      "SortDir": "Asc"
    }
  ],
  "PageNumber": 0,
  "PageSize": 0,
  "FilterExpression": "([Status] != 0) "
}
```

We didn't realize (didn't have enough knowledge) the main major issue with the `FilterExpression` value until yesterday one of our reviewers notified us with examples like

```
"FilterExpression": "[Status] != 0" - ANY SQL injection query can go here
```

At this point altering all the stored procedures, web part of referring it, API and Mobile App will be time-consuming which management is not understanding.

We understand very lately this is a very bad way to code and for now, we can only fix this in a shortcut way until we change entire code.

So please share suggestions, ways to handle the easy attacks. From C# or from SQL Server stored procedure, how can we validate if a `WhereExpression` / `FilterExpression` is a secure valid statement?

We started altering from C# with a token identifier to throw exceptions in case if unexpected keywords found (such as `ADD, ALTER, DROP, EXEC, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, TRUNCATE`)

Comment: Are you sure that writing a full fledged parser of any conceivable way to do sql injection is less expensive than redesign your bad design?

Comment: Try going the other way around. Identify all the valid `FilterExpression`s currently used, see if you can reduce these to a few forms that can be matched with some regexes and reject everything else while you work on an alternate API that doesn't have the problem. "Default deny" is more secure than "default accept".

Comment: I am just curious, what was the driver/motivation behind this?

Comment: The best way to prevent sql injection .NET is to use parameterization

Comment: Trying to understand the existing situation, do the stored procedures generate the dynamic SQL or is it generated in C#?

Comment: @Steve I had the same question to the developers, since system is using one Extension Class to handle "ToJson" Method which then converts advanced filter like stated In Question into JSON - so developers trying to add shortcut patch work for now and Yes then Plan is to rewrite everything into Parameterized SP's.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, tried adding Regular Expression of Validation. So Major WhereExpression contains conditions such as [Status] != 0 and [Type] = 'Regular'  and [ParentID] = 3 (The values gets filled based on User Selection of filters from Admin) - I couldn't see way to add Regular Expression Validation for this.

Comment: @JackWhipnert Dynamic SQL based on User filter Selection and the samething exposed as API for Mobile APP - The API will work only if they have Valid User Admin access JWT token but then since the WhereExpression currently can take any value once any user gets admin access.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences (working on API for banking purpose), it looks like we have the same problem here. I once made a API that was integrated with any stored procedure, so in my case, the API will treat stored procedure like action/endpoint (API is just like a broker or stored procedure executor).

The stored procedure will receive the data from API in JSON format (string), but a problem arose when the security team discovered a SQL injection problem. So, my team agreed to **return** any request with **Bad Request** that contain or indicates SQL syntax in JSON.

In my case, I added a simple validation filters (add function SQL injection checker in DB) that indicate this data can be trusted or not, when data can be **trusted** then it will be processed, Otherwise I use a raise error mechanism and not to process the JSON in the stored procedure then returned as error to the API.

Simple validation filters function that I used it's only to detect if JSON contain common SQL syntax

E.g. `SELECT, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP`, etc.

Sorry, I can only give advice to you, because currently, I can't access my work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I'd convert the commands to Prepared SQL Statements, which are parameterized (as RiceRiceBaby suggested).  Given the daily reports of companies being hacked, your management should be *insisting* that you fix it.  Beyond that, point out that Prepared SQL Statements are more efficient because the server can cache the execution plans.  Plans for dynamic SQL are not saved.